# Redirect to url that doesno't have www by jsoup

Tags: url, redirect, jsoup, reload

I have login into site with jsoup, got all the contents of next page after login. There is a link named Quoting, when I click on this link it redirects to new URL (in code no 1)
 which further reloads to url in code number 2. But my code is not leading me to url no 2. Can anybody tell where am I making a mistake ?

Here is my code. I did it with two options but none is working .

1)

```
Document doc2  = Jsoup.connect("https://www.infinityagents.com/AgencyServices/ForwardOnelinkServlet")
                 .cookie("JSESSIONID", sessionID)
                 .timeout(300000)
                 .followRedirects(true)
                .post();
```

2)

```
Connection.Response docd  = Jsoup.connect("https://webrater.infinityagents.com/start.do")
                 .cookie("JSESSIONID", sessionID)
                 .followRedirects(true)
                .execute();
```

Comment: What do you mean by not redirecting to URL 2? Do you get any error?

Comment: in actual site my destination link is number 2, but it directly doesn't opens, it opens from code 1 and then this reloads it to link 2. 
But here I am connecting via jsoup.If I write code (1) then it doesn't redirects me to my destination link 2. and if I write code 2 then it gives me error of url..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably after login it keeps some data in session or some form data and it expects these value for subsequent access. You need to find out these and supply it. Another case would be it may checking the source of redirect. Are you getting a 403 error? In that case try setting the referrer like

```
Connection.Response docd  = Jsoup.connect("https://webrater.infinityagents.com/start.do")
                 .cookie("JSESSIONID", sessionID)
                 .referrer("https://webrater.infinityagents.com/start.do")
                 .followRedirects(true)
                 .execute();
```

Based on the exception I think you have the certificate issue. Try the following

1. **Get the ssl certificate from the site** : This could be done in diffierent way. Easiest would be via browser. In most of the browsers the URl will show the certificate details. You could click on them an select view certificate. Then if you are using IE & chrome go to details tab and click "Copy to file" button. In firefox again goto details tab and click "Export" button. This will give you a .cer (Crypto Shell Extension) file. Alternatively if the browser didnt help you can use [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/) to get the certificate using the command `openssl s_client -connect {HOSTNAME}:{PORT} -showcerts`.(I havent tried this ;))
2. **Create .jks file** : Now you need to convert the .cer file to .jks (Java Key Store) file. Java ships with a keytool.exe file. You can find it either in jdk_folder\bin or in jre_folder\bin. Issue the command `keytool -import -v -file path_to_yourfile.cer -keystore path_to_your.jks -storepass anypassword`
3. **Set javax.net.ssl.trustStore property** : Before invoking jsoup set this system property like below.

   `System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "path_to_your.jks");
   Connection.Response docd  = Jsoup.connect("https://webrater.infinityagents.com/start.do")
            .cookie("JSESSIONID", sessionID)
            .referrer("https://webrater.infinityagents.com/start.do")
            .followRedirects(true)
            .execute();`

Comment: no I dont get 403 error. I get this error.....


javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested targetjavax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: Updated the answer. Hope that helps. :)

Comment: I did this.My cacerts file is in jre/lib/security. I gave the path but now I get this exception.............



javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested targetjavax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: That is weird.. Another possibility is the jre you are trying to run the program with might not be the same jre folder you are looking into. Just a wild guess. Alternatively check this http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target/. This might help.